# Decide where to store uploade file ( path )

Tags: java, spring

I have an app where user can upload file with additional info about it, such as description.

Now what i do is:

1. predefine the `PATH` where the files are stored ( so for example for server it will be at /files/ or for AWS url to aws )
2. user uploads file
3. file is saved, at location `PATH/userId/uploaded file name`
4. service that saves file returns whole path
5. the informations about file ( including path where it was stored ) is stored in DB.

So smth like this:

```
@Service
public class DiskSaveFileService implements SaveFileService {

    @Value("${file.path}")
    private String path;

    @Override
    public String saveFile(String fileName, byte[] bytes) {
        Path targetLocation = Paths.get(path + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(targetLocation.getParent());
            Files.write(targetLocation, bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SaveFileException("Saving file failed", e);
        }
        return targetLocation.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean safeDeleteFile(String fileName) throws SaveFileException {
        Path targetLocation = Paths.get(path + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            Files.delete(targetLocation);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And service:

```
UserEntity user = userUtilService.getLoggedUser();
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
String path = user.getId() + "/" + fileName;
try{
   String location = saveFileService.saveFile(path, uploadedFile.getBytes());
   FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity();
   fileEntity.setPath(location);
   ....
   fileRepository.save(fileEntity);
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException | SaveFileException | IOException e) {
        deleteFile(path);
        throw new RecipeServiceException("Error creating recipe!", e);
}
```

However if user wanted to upload two separate files, that happens to have same name, this would overwritte them, as both files would be saved in the same path.

What is the best way to determine where exactly to store path? I first wanted to save the file as
`PATH/userId/id of entity/name of the file`

However in that case i would need to save info about file to database, then save the file ( so i will have generated ID of row ), and then update entity of location. So i would have extra database hit.

What are some best ways to decide the path then? Methods that would actually makes sense.

Comment: This question seems to be you asking us to tell you what your project's requirements should be.  This is the wrong way around.  You are the person who should be explaining to us what the requirements are.  For what it is worth, the only answer I can give is "the best way will depend on what you are trying to achieve".

Comment: Consider this.  Suppose a user is permitted to upload 2 different files with the same name "X".  And suppose that one doesn't overwrite the other.  What should happen when the user tries to retrieve "X"?  What should they get?  One file?  Both files?  How would they tell the two apart? What if they only want one?  How would they specify which one?  When you are trying to design something like this, you need to think about how it is going to be used.  In sufficient detail that you can decide whether your design is actually going to make sense ... to the people who are going to use it.